# Shiny for non-interactive GUI

Tags: r, shiny

I have a R script that is fairly automated, such that only 4 user inputs are required at the top of the script (paths to specific files or folders where data is, and where outputs should be written).  I'm interested in building a simple GUI for this script and it seems that Shiny is the way to do this.  But from the little I understand so far, it seems that the server function `server<-function(input,output){}` has to have an output like `renderPlot` for example.

However, what I really want is just a section for inputs, and then a button that says "Go!" and the user inputs are simply inputted into my script.

So the question is, can one make a Shiny GUI without having a specific outputs section?  Or is there some other package I should be using for this?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, the output can be anything, like the button you mentioned. You should probably follow one of the begginer tutorials to understand shiny better(https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html). You can comment the parts of the code related to plot outputs and see that it doesnt break.

Comment: Yeah, "output" could be just a message that says "script done".

Comment: Wow, ok didn't know it could be that simple, thank you both!

Comment: You might consider [Shiny gadgets](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/introducing-shiny-gadgets-interactive-tools/?_ga=2.139592179.1165130527.1638907279-1277764549.1638907279) and [miniUI](https://github.com/rstudio/miniUI)

Comment: Also check out shiny flexdashboard: https://rstudio.github.io/flexdashboard/articles/shiny.html See the examples link too. It's an easy way to get up and running with a shiny UI.  Also the shinyWidets and shinythemes packages are useful for easily adding more style to your flexdashboard UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example app with one go button, zero outputs and 4 inputs. Inside the server i used `observeEvent()` so each time the button 'Go' is pressed, 4 variables are created and then a script is executed with `source()`. Note the argument `local = TRUE` to tell R where to look those 4 variables.

The **script** will be called `print_four_variables.R` and is located inside the same project directory. It only contains one line.

`print(paste(a,b,c,d, sep = ' and '))`

app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput('a', "Insert a:",value = 1),
  numericInput('b', "Insert b:",value = 2),
  numericInput('c', "Insert c:", value = 3),
  numericInput('d', "Insert d:", value = 4)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    a <- input$a
    b <- input$b
    c <- input$c
    d <- input$d
    
    source('print_four_variables.R',local = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```